# I'm having a UV map problem

Tags: uv

I need some help with a UV-mapping problem I've stepped into. When I exported the lowpolied mesh from zbrusch to blender, I was going to create UV-Maps there because it thought it would be much easier to create seams than in zbrusch. But after I've created seams and unwrapped the mesh, the faces on one side of the unwrapped mesh is bigger than on the other side. The meshes should be unwrapped on an equal scale, not individually. So, what did I do wrong? Please, help me.[image]

Comment: You should add more seams. Make seams to separate: tail, legs, torso, arms, head...

Comment: I tested out on the tail and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: If this has answered your question, please consider accepting the answer

Comment: @Derrick I fully accept my answer for now, until I've encounter an error that I cannot figure out how to solve it. Solidly swear.

Comment: My mistake - I forgot that you could not accept an answer without one being posed (eg can not accept @NMachado comment) :)